# AdminDirectory not showing up on code completion in Appmaker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-app-maker

- I have added Google Directory Admin API in the Advanced Services of App Settings in App maker.
- Enabled Admin Directory for my project in cloud console.

Still Admin Directory does not show up on code completion in the server side script in Appmaker.

Note: Its showing up in Appscript

Any clues why its not working in Appmaker?

Comment: Different products.

Comment: That's right, different products. If you really want autocompletion so bad, write the code in apps script and then paste it to appmaker. I used to do that until I got used to all apps script features.